# rm: .filename not removed: Disc quota exceeded

Tags: linux, unix, quota

This is the full file name I get when I do `ls -lt` from my current directory.

```
EXPORT_v1x0_20120811_11_T_065800_070000.dat.gz
```

File names also consist of date as well. In the above file date is `20120811`.

So I am trying to delete all the files which starts with `EXPORT_v1x0` and whose date is less than `20120825`.

I am using the below script from the command line to delete the files

```
find . -name "EXPORT_v1x0*" | awk -F'_' '$3<20120825' | xargs rm
```

But whenever I use the above command to delete the files, I always get this below exception.

```
rm: ./EXPORT_v1x0_20120811_11_T_065800_070000.dat.gz not removed: Disc quota exceeded
```

Can anyone tell me what does this exception means? And how to overcome this problem?

I am running `SunOS`.

```
bash-3.00$ uname -a
SunOS lvsaishdc3in0001 5.10 Generic_142901-02 i86pc i386 i86pc
```

Comment: Maybe it helps to *truncate* the file first, with `echo -n > EXPORT_v1x0_20120811_11_T_065800_070000.dat.gz`.

Comment: What version of SunOS are you using? What's the output of `quota -v`?

Comment: Updated the question with version name as well. I am running `5.10` If I interpret correctly the version name. And I tried `quota -v` but it says `quota: command not found`. Why?

Comment: @AntonKovalenko, Can you tell me how should I truncate the files. I tried the way you told me as well. `echo -n > EXPORT_v1x0_20120811_11_T_065800_070000.dat.gz`. Again I got same `Disc Quota Exception as well`

Comment: You're on ZFS. do `cp /dev/null EXPORT_v1x0_20120811_11_T_065800_070000.dat.gz` and you should be able to rm the file afterwards.

Comment: Do you want me to do `cp /dev/null` on all the files or only one files? I tried that on only one file but it gives me same exception as soon as I did `cp /dev/null filename`. `Disc quota exceeded`.

Comment: All the files. It's a ZFS 'feature' where you need a little bit more space before you can rm the files.

Comment: So how can I add this `dev/null` thing in my whole script that I am using in my question? I tried several combinations but I am not able to make that thing work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to do something like `cat /dev/null > file` (or `echo > file`) to get back under the quota such that you can use rm again.

Comment: Thanks Paul for the suggestion. If I need to add this `/dev/null` in my command as I mentioned in my question then how should I modify it, so that I am not getting this exception again? Any thoughts?

Comment: You should try it for a *single* file (preferably a big one) to get under quota, then `find` and `rm` might begin to work again. I don't know, maybe a file deletion wants to allocate a block for the directory first (yep, strange).

Comment: Anton is correct: it'd be best to truncate one file, then run the full command to rm them all (rm should work once you get back under the quota). You could first run your find using the -size flag and use that to identify the candidates for truncation.

Comment: I tried truncating the files as you told me. `echo -n > EXPORT_v1x0_20120811_11_T_065800_070000.dat.gz`. Again I got same `Disc Quota Exception as well`.

Answer (score 2):

Delete manually the tiniest files that you find until you go below quota, then you will be able to delete with the standard methods.

I don't know why @Volodymyr Savchenko's answer was downvoted. Actually that was the only trick that worked for me too.

I am working in a HPC and I ran out of quota.

-Trying pretty much any command was taking ages.

-`rsync` remotely with --remove-source-files was not working:

```
rsync -avz --remove-source-files -e "ssh -p ####" usr@host:path/file.dat ./
receiving file list ... done
rsync: sender failed to remove file.dat: Disk quota exceeded (122)
```

-rm most of the files was not working:

```
[usr@server ~]$ rm  path/file.dat
rm: cannot remove 'path/file.dat': Disk quota exceeded
```

-doing

```
cat /dev/null path/file
```

would apparently work, but rm'ing it wouldn't (yet with the quota exceeded error message) (which I cannot understand why).

Nevertheless, deleting tinny files that I had only 'touched', (i.e., empty files with very tinny size) would work, and gave me the chance to go below quota and be able to delete files normally.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that either you don't have permissions to remove the file or it's read only. Try rm -f.
The quota message comes from something trying to write to disk.

Comment: You can actually use disk in the sense that you have to write to a directory when you call unlink - the syscall rm uses.  Over quota means no write access.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and none of the usually suggested solutions, the ones you list, worked.

But I realized that it was possible to delete the smallest files < 1kb. I just had to find enough small files to be able again to clean up large ones with rm.

edit: I want to clarify that things like `cat /dev/null > some-file` did not work for me. It was one of the suggested solutions I mentioned.